# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"; detached entity passed to persist (in Java)

Tags: java, database, exception, entity, jpa-2.0

So, I am trying to put my data from swing action listener in sql database.

this is part of my action listener code that triggers putting data in database

```
poruka = "U suficitu ste ~ " + brojKalorija
                            + " kalorija.";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, poruka);

                    Podaci noviPodaci = new Podaci(brojKalorija, danInt,
                            mjesecInt, godinaInt, proteiniInt,
                            ugljikohidratiInt, mastiInt, godineInt,
                            masaInt, aktivnostInt, hrInt);
                    DatabaseUtils.spremiPodatke(noviPodaci);
                }
```

This is important part of DatabaseUtils:

```
public class DatabaseUtils {

public static void spremiPodatke(Podaci podaci) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernatePersistenceUnit");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(podaci);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

This is podaci.java, it gets all data:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "podaci.podaci_izracuna")

public class Podaci {

@Id
@Column(name = "brojKalorija_ID")
@GeneratedValue
private double brojKalorijaId;

@Column(name = "dan")
private int dan;
.
.
.
public Podaci(double brojKalorijaId, int dan, int mjesec, int godina, int proteini,
        int ugljikohidrati, int masti, int godine, int masa, int aktivnost, int hr) {
        this.brojKalorijaId = brojKalorijaId;
        this.dan = dan;
        this.mjesec = mjesec;
        this.godina = godina;
        this.proteini = proteini;
        this.ugljikohidrati = ugljikohidrati;
        this.masti = masti;
        this.godine = godine;
        this.masa = masa;
        this.aktivnost = aktivnost;
        this.hr = hr;

}
public double getBrojKalorijaId() {
    return brojKalorijaId;
}

public int getDan() {
    return dan;
}
.
.
(other getters)
```

Database looks like this:

```
create schema podaci;
create table podaci.podaci_izracuna(
brojKalorija_ID decimal (7,2) generated always as identity,
dan int not null,
mjesec int not null,
godina int not null,
proteini int not null,
ugljikohidrati int not null,
masti int not null,
godine int,
masa int,
aktivnost int,
heartRate int,
primary key (brojKalorija_ID)
);
```

Persistence:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0"> 
<persistence-unit name="HibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
<class>podaci.Podaci</class> 
<properties> 
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> 
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/potrosnjaKalorija"/> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="seminar"/> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="seminar"/> 
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/> 
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
</properties> 
</persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

Sorry for a lot of code, when I run that file with action listener I get this message:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: podaci.Podaci
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)

and so on...

I have no experience in databases, I think persistence is where it all went wrong, hope ypu can help.

Comment: database is empty, there are only columns dan, mjesec etc... I want to save my data entered in swing screen. I enter there date, number of proteins, carbs etc. and I need that saved in my database. so, new entity I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the database to generate the @Id property (brojKalorijaId), but you are setting it in the constructor.

Change your constructor to *not* set the brojKalorijadId property.  When the entity is persisted, the database will create a unique value for the @Id.

or

Add a new property to the Entity that will hold the database generated @Id.

Comment: oh. so no ID in constructor. but still, I need that brojKalorija value, should I create it like this:
`
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer ID;

@Column(name = "brojKalorija")
private double brojKalorija;`

and recreate database columns of course, with brojKalorija as double and ID as int (primary key)?